# Notation for an approximately defined interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a concise notation to express the following "inequality"?

$$a\lesssim x\lesssim b$$

For proper inequalities like $a< x\leq b$ we write $x\in(a, b]$, or sometimes also $x\in]a, b]$. Is there a way to express an approximate inequality in a similar way? Something like

$$x\tilde{\in}[a, b]$$

with "$\tilde{\in}$" meaning something like "approximately in"? Or should I just use the approximate inequality expression as displayed above?

Comment: Either works really; so long as the symbol is properly introduced and defined, I can't imagine many people might take issue. (That said, I haven't seen the notion before, so maybe there's a standard I'm unaware of.)